# put an icon on top of the graph in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I want to put an icon on the top of the shaft and graphics. I do not know how, I am new to this and would be grateful if I can help.

https://jsfiddle.net/apg8euad/

```
c3.generate({
        data: {
            x: 'fecha',
            xFormat: '%d-%m-%Y', // 'xFormat' can be used as custom format of 'x'
            columns:  [[                "Precio",0,547324,515740,515740,236644,544576,515740,547324,547324,547324,544576,147184,120000],["fecha","20-05-2016","27-05-2016","03-06-2016","10-06-2016","17-06-2016","24-06-2016","01-07-2016","08-07-2016","15-07-2016","22-07-2016","29-07-2016","05-08-2016","12-08-2016"]],    
            type:'bar'

        },


        legend: {
              show: true
        },

        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    format: '%Y-%m-%d'
                }
            },
             y : {
                  tick: {
                  format: d3.format("$,")
                   }
             }

        }


});
```

in this image I put a red rectangle. that's the position I want this icon. (The icon can be any image)
[image]

Comment: You can put an image in like so : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/apg8euad/1/ In the css is where you position it. Or you could get the positions of the top of the tick and draw there

Comment: @thatOneGuy but not always graphical be that size. if the graph varies its size, this would not work.

Comment: Thats why I said get the positions of the y axis and adjust the images position based on that

Comment: get bounding box of the axis and work from there